# web portal development in java platform

Tags: java

what is the tool to develop a web portal in java platform and what is the lanugage used in it core java or jsp.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393/what-java-portal-server-do-you-use

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using: [Play!](http://www.playframework.org/) framework. It's quite similar to Rails and Django.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JBOSS portals which jars are available for Eclipse IDE.
You can refer **JBoss Portal Server Development** book by **Ramanujam Rao**.It is very good reference book, also you can go to this link http://www.jboss.org/jbossportal

And Both Java and JSP technologies are used for portal development.